# Use session initiation protocol on Android as service

Tags: java, android, sip

i'm trying to implement a SIP Client on Android application using native Session Initiation protocol.

Everything is woking fine if i create an Activity and put the following code :

```
public class WalkieTalkieActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {


public String sipAddress = null;

public SipManager manager = null;
public SipProfile me = null;
public SipAudioCall call = null;
public IncomingCallReceiver callReceiver;

private static final int CALL_ADDRESS = 1;
private static final int SET_AUTH_INFO = 2;
private static final int UPDATE_SETTINGS_DIALOG = 3;
private static final int HANG_UP = 4;


private final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO = 1;
private final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_USE_SIP = 2;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_walkietalkie);
    //initRecorderParameters(new int[]{8000, 11025, 16000, 22050, 44100});

    //Richiedo i vari permessi
    if (!hasUseSipPermission()) { requestUseSipPermission(); }
    //Rchiedo i vari permessi
    if (!hasRecordAudioPermission()) { requestRecordAudioPermission(); }


    if (!SipManager.isVoipSupported(this)) {

        //Visualizzo il messaggio voip non supportato e torno alla dahboard
        Toast.makeText(WalkieTalkieActivity.this, "Voip non supportato su questo telefono", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent dashboard = new Intent(WalkieTalkieActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        // passo all'attivazione dell'activity page1.java
        startActivity(dashboard);
        finish();
    }

    if (!SipManager.isApiSupported(this)) {

        //Visualizzo il messaggio voip non supportato e torno alla dahboard
        Toast.makeText(WalkieTalkieActivity.this, "API non supportate su questo telefono", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent dashboard = new Intent(WalkieTalkieActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        // passo all'attivazione dell'activity page1.java
        startActivity(dashboard);
        finish();
    }




    // "Push to talk" can be a serious pain when the screen keeps turning off.
    // Let's prevent that.
    //getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    // use this to start and trigger a service
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SipEngine.class);
    // potentially add data to the intent
    i.putExtra("KEY1", "Value to be used by the service");
    this.startService(i);

    initializeManager();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
// When we get back from the preference setting Activity, assume
// settings have changed, and re-login with new auth info.
initializeManager();
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (call != null) {
        call.close();
    }

    closeLocalProfile();

    if (callReceiver != null) {
        this.unregisterReceiver(callReceiver);
    }
}


public void initializeManager() {
    if(manager == null) {
        manager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
    }

    initializeLocalProfile();
}

/**
 * Logs you into your SIP provider, registering this device as the location to
 * send SIP calls to for your SIP address.
 */
public void initializeLocalProfile() {
    if (manager == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (me != null) {
        closeLocalProfile();
    }

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    //String username = prefs.getString("namePref", "");
    //String domain = prefs.getString("domainPref", "");
    //String password = prefs.getString("passPref", "");

    String username = "username";
    String domain = "domain";
    String password = "password";

    // Set up the intent filter.  This will be used to fire an
    // IncomingCallReceiver when someone calls the SIP address used by this
    // application.
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.vohippo.INCOMING_CALL");
    callReceiver = new IncomingCallReceiver();
    this.registerReceiver(callReceiver, filter);


    try {

        Log.d("VOHIPPOSERVICE", "PROVO A REGISTRARE");

        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
        builder.setPassword(password);

        //Costruisco il builder
        me = builder.build();

        //Intent
        Intent i = new Intent();

        i.setAction("android.vohippo.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        manager.open(me, pi, null);


        // This listener must be added AFTER manager.open is called,
        // Otherwise the methods aren't guaranteed to fire.

        manager.setRegistrationListener(me.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {


            public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                updateStatus("Registering with SIP Server...");
                //updateNotification(ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.colorPrimary), "Attivazione in corso...");
            }

            public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                updateStatus("Ready");
                //updateNotification(ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.colorPrimary), "Servizio disponibile");
            }

            public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                                             String errorMessage) {
                updateStatus("Registration failed.  Please check settings.");
                //updateNotification(ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.colorPrimary), "Servizio non disponibile");
            }
        });
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        updateStatus("Connection Error.");
        //updateNotification(ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.colorPrimary), "Errore di connessione");

    } catch (SipException se) {
        updateStatus("Connection error.");
        //updateNotification(ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.colorPrimary), "Errore connessione");
    }
}
/**
 * Closes out your local profile, freeing associated objects into memory
 * and unregistering your device from the server.
 */


public void closeLocalProfile() {
    if (manager == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        if (me != null) {
            manager.close(me.getUriString());
        }
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        Log.d("WalkieTalkieActivity", "Failed to close local profile.", ee);
    }
}




/**
 * Make an outgoing call.
 */
public void initiateCall() {

    Toast.makeText(WalkieTalkieActivity.this, "Chiamata lanciata", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    updateStatus(sipAddress);

    try {
        SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
            // Much of the client's interaction with the SIP Stack will
            // happen via listeners.  Even making an outgoing call, don't
            // forget to set up a listener to set things up once the call is established.
            @Override
            public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {

                call.startAudio();
                call.setSpeakerMode(true);
                if (call.isMuted()) {
                    call.toggleMute();
                }
                updateStatus(call);

                Toast.makeText(WalkieTalkieActivity.this, "Chiamata stabilita", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {

                Toast.makeText(WalkieTalkieActivity.this, "Chiamata terminata", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                updateStatus("Ready.");
            }
        };

        call = manager.makeAudioCall(me.getUriString(), sipAddress, listener, 30);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity", "Error when trying to close manager.", e);
        if (me != null) {
            try {
                manager.close(me.getUriString());
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity",
                        "Error when trying to close manager.", ee);
                ee.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (call != null) {
            call.close();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Updates the status box at the top of the UI with a messege of your choice.
 * @param status The String to display in the status box.
 */
public void updateStatus(final String status) {
    // Be a good citizen.  Make sure UI changes fire on the UI thread.
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TextView labelView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sipLabel);
            labelView.setText(status);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Updates the status box with the SIP address of the current call.
 * @param call The current, active call.
 */
public void updateStatus(SipAudioCall call) {
    String useName = call.getPeerProfile().getDisplayName();
    if(useName == null) {
        useName = call.getPeerProfile().getUserName();
    }
    updateStatus(useName + "@" + call.getPeerProfile().getSipDomain());
}

/**
 * Updates whether or not the user's voice is muted, depending on whether the button is pressed.
 * @param v The View where the touch event is being fired.
 * @param event The motion to act on.
 * @return boolean Returns false to indicate that the parent view should handle the touch event
 * as it normally would.
 */
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (call == null) {
        return false;
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && call != null && call.isMuted()) {
        call.toggleMute();
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && !call.isMuted()) {
        call.toggleMute();
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, CALL_ADDRESS, 0, "Call someone");
    menu.add(0, SET_AUTH_INFO, 0, "Edit your SIP Info.");
    menu.add(0, HANG_UP, 0, "End Current Call.");

    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case CALL_ADDRESS:
            showDialog(CALL_ADDRESS);
            break;
        case SET_AUTH_INFO:
            updatePreferences();
            break;
        case HANG_UP:
            if(call != null) {
                try {
                    call.endCall();
                } catch (SipException se) {
                    Log.d("WalkieTalkieActivity",
                            "Error ending call.", se);
                }
                call.close();
            }
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case CALL_ADDRESS:

            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            final View textBoxView = factory.inflate(R.layout.call_address_dialog, null);
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Call Someone.")
                    .setView(textBoxView)
                    .setPositiveButton(
                            android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                    EditText textField = (EditText)
                                            (textBoxView.findViewById(R.id.calladdress_edit));
                                    sipAddress = textField.getText().toString();
                                    initiateCall();

                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton(
                            android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                    // Noop.
                                }
                            })
                    .create();

        case UPDATE_SETTINGS_DIALOG:
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage("Please update your SIP Account Settings.")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            updatePreferences();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(
                            android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                    // Noop.
                                }
                            })
                    .create();
    }
    return null;
}

public void updatePreferences() {
    //Intent settingsActivity = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
    //        SipSettings.class);
    //startActivity(settingsActivity);
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_USE_SIP:

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(WalkieTalkieActivity.this, "Permission Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(WalkieTalkieActivity.this, "Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO:

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(WalkieTalkieActivity.this, "Permission Granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(WalkieTalkieActivity.this, "Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
}


//Controllo che il sistema abbia il permesso di registrare audio
private boolean hasRecordAudioPermission(){

    boolean hasPermission = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

    Log.d("VOHIPPO", "Permesso di registrare audio? " + hasPermission);
    return hasPermission;
}



private void requestRecordAudioPermission(){

    String requiredPermission = Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            requiredPermission)) {
            Toast.makeText(WalkieTalkieActivity.this, "Quest applicazione richiede il permesso di registrare audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // request the permission.
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{requiredPermission},
            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);
}

//Controllo che il sistema abbia il permesso di registrare audio
private boolean hasUseSipPermission(){

    boolean hasPermission = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.USE_SIP) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

    Log.d("VOHIPPO", "Permesso di usare sip? " + hasPermission);
    return hasPermission;
}



private void requestUseSipPermission(){

    String requiredPermission = Manifest.permission.USE_SIP;

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            requiredPermission)) {
        Toast.makeText(WalkieTalkieActivity.this, "Quest applicazione richiede il permesso di usare SIP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // request the permission.
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{requiredPermission},
            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_USE_SIP);
}
```

but if i create a service and try to do the same into this service i have no errors, but my client doesn't register with the server.

This is the code i put into the service :

```
public class SipEngine extends IntentService {

public String sipAddress = null;

public SipManager manager = null;
public SipProfile me = null;
public SipAudioCall call = null;
public IncomingCallReceiver callReceiver;

private static final int CALL_ADDRESS = 1;
private static final int SET_AUTH_INFO = 2;
private static final int UPDATE_SETTINGS_DIALOG = 3;
private static final int HANG_UP = 4;

private int NOTIFICATION = 10002; //Any unique number for this notification

public SipEngine() {
    super("SipEngine");
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
    // Gets data from the incoming Intent
    String dataString = workIntent.getDataString();
    initializeManager();
    sendNotification();
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


//@Override
//public void onStart() {
//    super.onStart();
    // When we get back from the preference setting Activity, assume
    // settings have changed, and re-login with new auth info.
    //initializeManager();
//}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (call != null) {
        call.close();
    }

    closeLocalProfile();

    if (callReceiver != null) {
        this.unregisterReceiver(callReceiver);
    }
}


public void initializeManager() {
    if(manager == null) {
        manager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
    }

    initializeLocalProfile();
}

/**
 * Logs you into your SIP provider, registering this device as the location to
 * send SIP calls to for your SIP address.
 */
public void initializeLocalProfile() {
    if (manager == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (me != null) {
        closeLocalProfile();
    }

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    //String username = prefs.getString("namePref", "");
    //String domain = prefs.getString("domainPref", "");
    //String password = prefs.getString("passPref", "");

    String username = "username";
    String domain = "server";
    String password = "password";

    // Set up the intent filter.  This will be used to fire an
    // IncomingCallReceiver when someone calls the SIP address used by this
    // application.
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.vohippo.INCOMING_CALL");
    callReceiver = new IncomingCallReceiver();
    this.registerReceiver(callReceiver, filter);


    try {

        Log.d("VOHIPPOSERVICE", "PROVO A REGISTRARE");

        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
        builder.setPassword(password);

        //Costruisco il builder
        me = builder.build();

        //Intent
        Intent i = new Intent();

        i.setAction("android.vohippo.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        manager.open(me, pi, null);


        // This listener must be added AFTER manager.open is called,
        // Otherwise the methods aren't guaranteed to fire.

        manager.setRegistrationListener(me.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {


            public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                //updateStatus("Registering with SIP Server...");
                updateNotification(ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.colorPrimary), "Attivazione in corso...");
            }

            public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                //updateStatus("Ready");
                updateNotification(ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.colorPrimary), "Servizio disponibile");
            }

            public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                                             String errorMessage) {
                //updateStatus("Registration failed.  Please check settings.");
                updateNotification(ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.colorPrimary), "Servizio non disponibile");
            }
        });
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        //updateStatus("Connection Error.");
        //updateNotification(ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.colorPrimary), "Errore di connessione");

    } catch (SipException se) {
        //updateStatus("Connection error.");
        //updateNotification(ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.colorPrimary), "Errore connessione");
    }
}
/**
 * Closes out your local profile, freeing associated objects into memory
 * and unregistering your device from the server.
 */


public void closeLocalProfile() {
    if (manager == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        if (me != null) {
            manager.close(me.getUriString());
        }
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        Log.d("WalkieTalkieActivity", "Failed to close local profile.", ee);
    }
}









//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/**
 * Send simple notification using the NotificationCompat API.
 */
public void sendNotification() {

    // Use NotificationCompat.Builder to set up our notification.
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    //icon appears in device notification bar and right hand corner of notification
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_service_sip);

    // This intent is fired when notification is clicked
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://stacktips.com/"));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification.
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    // Large icon appears on the left of the notification
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_service_sip));

    // Content title, which appears in large type at the top of the notification
    builder.setContentTitle("Vohippo");

    int color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary);

    builder.setColor(color);

    // Content text, which appears in smaller text below the title
    builder.setContentText("491023456");

    // The subtext, whichppears under the text on newer devices.
    // This will show-up in the devices with Android 4.2 and above only
    builder.setSubText("Attendere...");


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Will display the notification in the notification bar
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION, builder.build());
}

/**
 * Send simple notification using the NotificationCompat API.
 */
public void updateNotification(int color, String status) {

    // Use NotificationCompat.Builder to set up our notification.
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    builder.setColor(color);

    // The subtext, which appears under the text on newer devices.
    // This will show-up in the devices with Android 4.2 and above only
    builder.setSubText(status);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Will display the notification in the notification bar
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION, builder.build());
}
```

Should i do something different into a service instead of a normal Activity?
Than k you.